# Why is a function wrap unside a function object not called in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have JavaScript function as object:

```
function hexMesh(){
     var side=25;
     console.log('hexMesh');

     function drawOver(){
     }
}
```

As you can see it has a function call `drawOver`.

I try to call it by using a constructor as follows:

```
window.onload = function() {
    hexMeshObj=new hexMesh();
    hexMeshObj.drawOver();
}
```

But it gives me error saying `undefined is not a function`

Now I know I could declare the function in the prototype of the object but I don't want to do that.

Here it is on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Snedden27/z4xfy6n8/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use JavaScript like that!

Solution: Use Class-like prototypes (please don't treat them as classes, although they provide inheritance)

```
var x = function(v){ this.test = v; } // This is your constructor
x.prototype.show = function(){ console.log("TEST", this.test); } // This is a prototype with this as a context

var y = new x(true);
y.show(); // Logs TEST true
```

Edit:
Alternatively (although the prototype way is better as it provides real [inheritance the oop way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript))

```
var x = function(v){
var context = this;
this.test = v;
this.show = function(){
    console.log('test', context.test)
});
```

Another alternative way is to use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind context if you need it.

Comment: It might be helpful to include some info as to why using prototypes is better than the second way.

Comment: Added reference. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I was looking for the alternate way, I knew I could do it using prototype but I didn't want the function to be in the prototype of the object as it doesn't make sense in my case, 

Thanks

Comment: I added info regarding bind. You can achieve  the same context (that's the extent of it) using bind(this). On a second note this question is not a duplicate as it does not ask for oop strictly in the manner that the referenced question is set.